# Croatia to Ljubljana (Slovenia) for U.S. citizens ok?

Tags: us-citizens, borders, croatia, slovenia

We are 2 middle aged couples traveling to Croatia in June 2015. We want to drive through Ljubljana (Slovenia) from Zagreb. We are U.S. Citizens, and of course we have passports. Is this an easy process? We will be headed to Pula.

Comment: Croatia is not yet part of the Schengen area, so it will be just another border crossing. Neither country requires US citizens to have a visa, for visits up to 90 days in a 180 day period.

Comment: @MichaelHampton actually because both countries are in the EU, I understand that they are consolidating their border posts, or at least some of them.  At these consolidated posts, one will need only to stop once rather than twice.  I haven't experienced this firsthand, however.

Comment: @phoog Right. Croatia is in the process of joining Schengen, so there may be reduced or no exit border controls here.

Comment: @phoog: I crossed back and forth between Slovenia and Croatia at the Kaštel  border crossing a few weeks ago and while the Croatian checkpoint has been closed, the Croatian border police has their own immigration check at the Slovenian checkpoint and you actually have to stop twice, once for Slovenian/Schengen exit control and once for Croatian immigration control. Even if both countries are in the EU, it is still an outer Schengen border and the passport control was relatively strict, even for me as a citizen of a Schengen country.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Interesting.  I crossed there a couple of summers ago, before Croatia joined the EU.  I don't remember the control being particularly rigorous.  If I recall correctly, I mistakenly showed my non-EU (US) passport to the Slovenian guards instead of my Schengen (NL) passport.  My wife showed her Croatian passport -- perhaps that was the reason for the relatively casual scrutiny.

Comment: @phoog Some crossings with Slovenia are joint, others not. The one on the road from Zagreb to Ljubljana is joint, while the one on the road from Zagreb to Maribor is not. Got fresh experience with both

Comment: @Crazydre I've only ever crossed that border on the Adriatic coast. Never been to Zagreb.

Answer (score 5):

As said by Michael Hampton, no additional documents other than passports are necessary for you, so: Yes, unless you come with a truck etc. (content check), it´s as easy as it can get.

Take (one of) the correct lane(s) for normal, private cars (see the symbols above in the picture, all border points look similar); hand your passport through the window, get it back, and drive on.

Note that the queue of waiting cars can get a bit long, especially in summer.

[Unconfirmed if it's still valid: In theory, at least at some locations there is an exit check of one country and an entry check of the other, but in practice, one part will check the passport and on the other side some policeman will stand around and just look at the cars while they drive past him.]

[image]
<sub>(source: [hudin.com](https://www.hudin.com/files/hudin/910.jpg))</sub>

Comment: This does not match my experience while crossing intra-EU, but outer Schengen borders several times within the last year. I have never managed to leave the Schengen area without proper exit controls, and it would be a severe violation of the Schengen regulations if one country would let people leave the Schengen area unaccounted for. It would also lead to definitive problems for all non-EU or non-EEC nationals leaving the Schengen area through these border crossings, since they would not have proper exit stamps to prove the time spent there.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I don´t fully understand what you´re getting at. Why do you think non-EU people won´t get stamps? About the rest, I didn´t mean that one country doesn´t care, but that the have some sort of agreement that one single person will do everything instead of one person of each country.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo About your other comment above: Well, that´s interesting... actually, I wasn´t in Croatia for more than three years, so maybe the really got stricter.

Comment: I am getting at you mentioning only a theoretical possibility of an exit check. If you are e.g. leaving Slovenia and entering Croatia (as in this case), the Slovenian border police is bound by the Schengen agreement to perform a regular exit check. For the purpose of immigration control, it does not really matter that the destination country is another EU country if it is not a Schengen country. I would hardly doubt that the Schengen agreement allows the Croatian border police to perform the exit control, making two checks (exit SLO and entry HR) essential.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Well, I´m no lawyer or anything like that, and I´m not saying you´re wrong (not at all), but I´m as sure as I can get that it did happen in the past. Even if it was illegal. (Well...confirmed cases of lazy and corrupt border guards in several countries around here do exist, asking for money from clueless people). OP: You don´t need to pay anything for crossing the border itself :) (custom stuff is another thing, if you have something applicable)

Comment: And watch the signs; some borders will have separate lanes for non-EU/EEA/Switzerland passport holders.

Answer (score 3):

Live 15 min from that border. There will be to lines. EU/EEA/CH and All other.
If you have EU/EEA/CH passport you have to get in the EU/EEA/CH line. You will need to show your passport of EU ID card. You will not be questioned, only your document will be checked if it is genuine. If you dont have EU/EEA/CH passport take "All others" and you will have to stop only on Slovenian side. (Croatian border does not operate). At Slovenian booth there will be Croatian officer who will take your passport and check it if you overstayed (etc) and you will get Croatian exit stamp (all non-EU/EEA/CH citizens get one). Then you will have to give your passport to a Slovenian border officer. He will check your passport and might question you why are you coming, do you have enough funds (etc) like all normal immigration controls. It my also happen that the officer dont ask you anything. If you satisfy immigration requirements you will get Entry Stamp. 
As both countries are in the EU there will be no Customs Controls.